# How do I adjust kubuntu's maximum screen resolution?

Tags: xrandr, resolution, kubuntu, asus

I am running Kubuntu 14.10. My screen resolution is currently at 1024 x 768, which xrandr states as the maximum resolution. The problem is, my screen should support a resolution of 1366 x 768. When I run *xrandr*, the following results:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 800 x 600, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
  1024x768        0.0* 
  800x600        61.0
```

The maximum should be 1366 x 768.

Ever since I installed my Linux dual boot (with Windows 7) on my Asus laptop, this has been in effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is to check that you have installed the proper driver for your video card, as general guide take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/23238/how-can-i-find-what-video-driver-is-in-use-on-my-system and once you are familiar with the topic search how to install compatible drivers for your video card